# Error with testing formbuilder in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I don't know why I get the error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
" I've tried every way to understand this error, but I can't
I tryng  test new setup for spec.ts, but now return error "Cannot read property 'form' of undefined" :
spec.ts

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidationService } from 'src/app/core/services/custom-validation/custom-validation.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/core/services/user/user.service';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';

describe('AccountComponent', () => {
  let accountComponent: AccountComponent;
  let fb:FormBuilder;
  let customValidator: CustomValidationService;
  let userService: UserService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AccountComponent],
      imports: [FormBuilder, CustomValidationService, UserService],
      providers:[FormBuilder]
    }).compileComponents();
  }))
 
  it('',fakeAsync(()=>{
    const testForm={
      username:'test',
      email: 'test@example.com'
    };
    accountComponent.form.controls['username'].setValue(testForm.username)

  }))
});
```

My component:

````
  form: FormGroup;
  formAlterPassword: FormGroup;  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.formAlterPassword = this.fb.group({
      currentPassword: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12)])],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12)])]      
    })
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your component relies on dependency injection to get an instance of FormBuilder, so you have to provide an instance to your test as well. Try something like this,

```
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;
 beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });
    fb = TestBed.inject<FormBuilder>(FormBuilder);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountComponent);
    accountComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Alternatively take a look at the answers here for some other ways you can provide the FormBuilder,

[Angular2 FormBuilder unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712150/angular2-formbuilder-unit-testing)

You also have to create an instance of the AccountComponent before you can access it's properties. I added that code to my original answer as well.

Comment: In this example you put in the link, I've been following it and it's returned an error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Comment: Can you add where/how you setup the provider to your code above?

Comment: I post a new setup

Comment: now error: Unexpected value 'FormBuilder' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Remove FormBuilder from the imports in your code above

Comment: now removed and return two errors: 
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UserService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

Comment: and this error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Comment: I don't know where the HTTPClient error is coming from, another test maybe? Because I don't see your component using HTTPClient. The second error is because you haven't created an instance of AccountComponent, look at the updated answer for how to do that.

Comment: I don't see any sense in giving error in userservice, I'm testing a specific component.
Even with the answer updated, it still gives an error in the form :(